# I'm getting an error for an unrecognized function within Auth0's node package, specifically in their AuthenticationClient and ManagementClient API

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, auth0, nestjs

[Here is a picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDVcc.png)

I went into the package and **found the exact function** the error says is unrecognized

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';
import { AuthenticationClient, ManagementClient } from 'auth0';
import { EnvConfig } from '../my/env/config';

const config = {
  domain: EnvConfig.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientId: EnvConfig.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: EnvConfig.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  audience: `https://${EnvConfig.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/api/v2/`,
};

@Injectable()
export class Auth0Service {
  public authenticationClient;
  public managementClient;

  constructor() {
    this.authenticationClient = AuthenticationClient(config);
    this.managementClient = ManagementClient(config);
  }
```

The error occurs upon the instantiation of both AuthenticationClient and ManagementClient. I've been using a boilerplate system for setting up any third party services and have never seen a function unrecognized. I've tried to reinstall the package but had no luck.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Drew, Which version of node.js are you using and how does your package.json looks like?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I'm blind and didn't see my lack of "new" next to my attempted instantiation..

```
(wrong)
this.authenticationClient = AuthenticationClient(config);

(correct)
this.authenticationClient = new AuthenticationClient(config);
```